# License to use Google Maps app that comes with iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my application I have "get directions" from the user's current location. When a user taps the location he wants to go to. I do

```
[[UIApplcation sharedApplication]openURL:googleMapsURL];
```

Do I need some sort of signing identity, license from Google to send the user to the native Google Maps app when the user wants directions if I want to send the App in to the Appstore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of any Licence from Google or any Signing identity to get approved from AppStore. You can show direction in Native Google Maps app. by opening the following URL string:

`http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=SOURCE_COORDINATES&daddr=DESTINATION_COORDINATES`.

Comment: Thanks! I already knew how to use it, just wondered if my app would get declined because of lack of license from Google :-) Appricate the quick response.